# during reboot stuck on "Samsung" logo

Tags: cyanogenmod, reboot, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

After installing CM9 on my Samsung Galaxy S+ (Plus) it gets stuck in the "SAMSUNG" screen whenever I restart, the very first screen (I guess). I have to press the Power button 10 seconds to restart when I come to that point. Did someone discover that kind of problem before, how can I solve the issue?

Comment: I have experienced something like this when I first flashed CM10 on my vibrant. I thought it was stuck so I pulled the battery, then rebooted in to recovery and reflashed (wiping data and cache) then rebooted. The screen was "stuck" there for some time again, but I let it go for a bit and it did eventually boot past it, it just took longer then I expected.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common outcome for many possible problems. If you can get in to clockworkmod(or whatever custom recovery) try reflashing cm9. If that doesn't work try doing a factory reset from recovery (clear data/factory reset) and then reflashing cm9.

On the international SGS you always had to flash cm-roms twice (on first flash it sets up the partitions and on the second flash it finaly flashes the rom).

If you still can't boot, flash a stock ROM with Odin (I think it is Odin you use for flashing stock ROMs, since it is Samsung device, if not use whatever is recomended on XDA-developers under topic named something like "restoring a stock ROM"), and check that it boots that. After that install root, recovery and cm as before.

If you still can't get it to boot after that, let us know.

Comment: My SGS+ is running correctly with CM9. I can boot (if phone was shut off) and shutdown correctly, only when explicitly **restarting** the problem occurs.

Comment: If everything else works ok, than this is most probably a bug in cm, or just a wierd conincidence in your particular configuration. Either way I would not worry about it since there is a simple workaround. If you want to restart it power it off and than back on. The whole thing is to small to lose sleep over it.